Cordova export canvas as a jpeg or png
That do one week that I try to write a file who can contain a ImageData from a canvas with a mine type png or jpeg .
so i have something as:
arrPixel.width = 480;
arrPixel.height = 480;
arrPixel.data[ 255, 255, 255 ect... ];

so where i write arrPixel to generate a .png with "image/png"?
on my pc i have
function Id( ParId )
{
    return document.getElementById( ParId );
}

var savePicture = document.createElement("a");
savePicture.setAttribute("id", "savePicture");
savePicture.setAttribute("href", "#");
savePicture.setAttribute("download", "pictures");
savePicture.innerHTML = "save";
Id("menuFileSave").appendChild( savePicture );
    

var download = "image" + ".png";
Id("savePicture").setAttribute("download", download );
Id("savePicture").setAttribute("href", Id("canvas").toDataURL("image/png") );

So on my PC with firefox the attribute download work very well.
But not if i transform my js with cordova for android 13.
I found a code as,
'
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS);
      
        function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile( download, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry);
        }
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter);
        }
        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
            
            console.log("Start creating image file");
            writer.seek(0);
            writer.write( "arrPixel ???" );
            console.log( writer );
            console.log("End creating image file. File created");
        }

What do i write inside the function write() to have a png or a jpeg ?
